# Installing cx_Oracle on 32 bit Anaconda: LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, cx-oracle, miniconda

I am on a 64 bit machine, but need to support a legacy 32 bit proprietary system.

I have miniconda 32 bit installed version 3.7.1, as well as a 32 bit oracle client. My `ORACLE_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are pointed to the correct 32 bit oracle client.

**I cannot install a 64 bit python since I need to interact with 32 bit legacy C libraries.**

It looks like miniconda's pip is attempting to install 64 bit cx_Oracle even though it is a 32 bit python installation.

`pip install cx_Oracle` results in the following error (edit: as well as `python -m pip install cx_Oracle`):

```
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
building 'cx_Oracle' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/odpi
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/odpi/src
gcc -pthread -B /path/to/miniconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DCXO_BUILD_VERSION=7.3.0 -Iodpi/include -Iodpi/src -I/path/to/miniconda3/include/python3.7m -c src/cxoBuffer.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/cxoBuffer.o
/path/to/miniconda3/include/python3.7m/pyport.h:699:2: error: 
#error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

It seems that pip is attempting to install 64 bit cx_Oracle, even though this is a 32 bit python. For example the `pip install cx_Oracle` command shows `x86_64` and is not using -m32 to build.

The same is true if I git clone an older version like cx_Oracle 5.3 and run python setup.py install.

How can I install 32 bit cx_Oracle on a 32 bit miniconda installation?

Answer (score 0):

Installing it using `conda` (located in the miniconda's bin directory next to `pip`) works.

```
./conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda cx_oracle
```

I'm not sure why using `pip` tried to install a 64 bit version.

Comment: Possibly because the pip you used is for a 64-bit Python installation? The best way to make sure you are using the "right" one, is to use this command: python -m pip install cx_Oracle

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga I used `python -m pip install cx_Oracle` previously but it had the same error message.

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga I suspect the issue has something to do with anaconda/miniconda 32 bit python and not your library, but I am unsure.

Comment: Probably they ran into the same issue, modified the *cx\_Oracle* sources, built them  *bz2*ed the package and uploaded it to the *conda* repo.